# Unable to update the DB values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two registration pages at first page i insert mandatory fields and after that i update some other details using the userid...userid is a identity column in DB so my update stored proc

```
  ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_update]

(@id int,@FormFiledBy varchar (50),@MaritalStatus varchar (50),@Height varchar (50),
@Religion varchar (50),@Caste varchar (100),
 @MotherTongue varchar(50),@Education varchar (100),@Occupation varchar(50),
 @CountryofResidence varchar (50),@EducationDetails varchar (100),@AnnualIncome varchar(50),
@CountryOfBirth varchar(50),@BirthPlace varchar(50),@TimeOfBirth nchar(10),@StarSign varchar (100),
@Gothram varchar (50),@Rassi varchar(50),@HavinChildren varchar(10),@PhysicalStatus varchar (100))

as
begin

update Profile_Master
 set FormFiledBy=@FormFiledBy,MaritalStatus=@MaritalStatus,Height=@Height,
Religion=@Religion,Caste=@Caste,MotherTongue=@MotherTongue,
Education=@Education,Occupation=@Occupation,CountryofResidence=@CountryofResidence,EducationDetails=@EducationDetails,
AnnualIncome=@AnnualIncome,CountryOfBirth=@CountryOfBirth,BirthPlace=@BirthPlace,TimeOfBirth=@TimeOfBirth,
StarSign=@StarSign,Gothram=@Gothram,Rassi=@Rassi,HavinChildren=@HavinChildren,PhysicalStatus=@PhysicalStatus

where UserId=@id
return
end
```

in my DAL

```
 public static int update(ProfileMasterBLL profileMasterBLL)
    {
        string userid = ProfileMasterDAL.GetUserIdByEmailID(profileMasterBLL.EmailID);

        SqlConnection conn = Generic.DBConnection.OpenConnection();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("sp_update", conn);
            cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormFiledBy", profileMasterBLL.FormFiledBy);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaritalStatus", profileMasterBLL.MaritalStatus);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", profileMasterBLL.Height);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Religion", profileMasterBLL.Religion);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Caste", profileMasterBLL.Caste);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Education", profileMasterBLL.Education);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", profileMasterBLL.Occupation);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryofResidence", profileMasterBLL.CountryofResidence);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EducationDetails", profileMasterBLL.EducationDetails);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryOfBirth", profileMasterBLL.CountryOfBirth);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthPlace", profileMasterBLL.BirthPlace);
```

in my UI

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get User ID from DAL
        int chk = 0;
        if (Session["EmailID"] != null)
        {
            emailID = Session["EmailID"].ToString();
        }
        ProfileMasterBLL prfbll = new ProfileMasterBLL();
        string userid = ProfileMasterDAL.GetUserIdByEmailID(emailID);
```

i am able to get the userid here but after this

```
     chk = ProfileMasterDAL.update(prfbll);
```

at here breakpoint jumps to update method and i am getting emailid as null and so i amgetting userid also null any help on this?

in my BAL

```
public class ProfileMasterBLL
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FormFiledBy { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public string HavinChildren { get; set; }
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
 }
```

in my first page i am catching the session value

```
  Session["EmailID"] = TextBox8.Text;
```

Comment: Where's the code that sets the session variable?  It sounds like the problem might be there.

Comment: The emailid comes from the first page...

Comment: What happen if you Session["EmailID"] is null?
Your code calls the update with an empty or null string.

Comment: Where are you writing it to the session variable?  What does the code look like?

Comment: In the ui page check my question...

Comment: have you stepped through your code Chandra using the Debugger..? are you getting any exceptions if so please explain where.. also where are you assigning Session]"EmailID"]
emailID = Session["EmailID"].ToString();
you are not even showing where you are getting the email address..

Comment: In your `update` method, you're accessing : `profileMasterBLL.EmailID` - but are you setting that at all? Your other code definitely **doesn't** show that! You're grabbing the `emailID` from the `Session`, you're using it to load the `userID` - but I don't ever see you **setting** that property on `profileMasterBLL` - check that!

Comment: I am not getting any exception or error but i am unable to populate userid using emailid....

Comment: Some what i am confused with this as i am getting user id value at GetUserIdByEmailID(string emailid) but after that when i am checking at chk = ProfileMasterDAL.update(prfbll); i am not getting emailid and userid is 0

Comment: Chandra.. are you expected to update the EmailID into the Database..? if so you need to add that to your SQL Update query as well as the 
cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId"), Session["EmailID"].ToString()); do you follow what I am saying..?

Comment: yeah i want to update the details using userid...i think there is no need to use cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId"), Session["EmailID"].ToString()); this im populating userid using emailid.....

Comment: check if you have `Session["EmailID"] = null` in page_load method on 2nd page, if you do remove that

Answer (score 0):

Try checking as well for Empty strings.
Also your UserId at somepoints is a string, instead of an int, where are you converting and handling the conversion errors. Try int.TryParse() before going to the DB call.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring string `emailID` so it will still be in scope after the `(Session["EmailID"] != null)` curly brackets:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Get User ID from DAL
       int chk = 0;

       string emailID = ""; 

       if (Session["EmailID"] != null)
       {
           emailID = Session["EmailID"].ToString();
       }
       ProfileMasterBLL prfbll = new ProfileMasterBLL();
       string userid = ProfileMasterDAL.GetUserIdByEmailID(emailID);
```